# Validating School Year

Tags: c#, date

Im asking about the `SchoolYear`.

just like this example

> 2013-2014 *(StartYear-EndYear)*

How to Validate if the user is actually enter the School Year (ex. `2013-2014`)

This what I have tried so far.

```
 private void TextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(studentLastSchoolAttendedSchoolYearTextBox.Text))
            {
                int fromYear = 0;
                int toYear = 0;
                string[] years = Regex.Split(studentLastSchoolAttendedSchoolYearTextBox.Text, @"-");

                fromYear = int.Parse(years.FirstOrDefault().ToString());
                if (fromYear.ToString().Length == 4)
                {
                    if (years.Count() > 1)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(years.LastOrDefault()))
                        {
                            toYear = int.Parse(years.LastOrDefault().ToString());
                            if (fromYear >= toYear)
                            {
                                e.Cancel = true;
                                MessageBox.Show("The 'From Year' must be lesser than to 'To Year'.\n\nJust leave as a empty to avoid validating.", Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid School range Year format.\nEx.: 2010-2011\n\nJust leave as empty to avoid validating.", Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        studentLastSchoolAttendedSchoolYearTextBox.Text = fromYear.ToString() + "-" + Convert.ToInt32(fromYear + 1).ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid School range Year format.\nEx.: 2010-2011\n\nJust leave as empty to avoid validating.", Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: For someone with such a **high** reputation this seems quite a **low** quality question!

Comment: _What_ is the correct format?

Comment: you should look regular expression.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Correct format, I would assume, is two years, separated by a - , and both years being consecutive.

Comment: It seems that.. the `SchoolYear` format is not commonly use `:D`

Comment: So now that you've posted your solution, what about your solution doesn't work?  Is it generating an error, if so, what is the error, and what types of inputs generate that error.

Comment: Im asking about what would the `SchoolYear` Format Mr @Servy

Comment: Are you asking us which strings you should accept, and which you should reject?

Comment: @spajce That's entirely unhelpful.  You came here and posted a code snippet of what you're using.  Why did you come here in the first place?  What is wrong with your solution?  Does it return an incorrect value in certain situations?  Does it throw an exception?  Is it too slow?  Is it not pretty enough?  Are you just bored and looking to kill some time?  What?

Comment: my question is not about.. homework or.. something like that, Im asking what would be the corret format of `SchoolYear`.. is that so not clear for us?

Comment: @spajce No, it's not clear at all.  You've apparently come here because you have a problem that you're looking to solve.  We have no idea what that problem is, so we cannot make any reasonable attempt at solving it.  Do you not know what valid input *ought* to be for your function, meaning you don't know what kinds of strings should be valid or not (outside of code, just looking at it yourself), if so, that's off topic and we can't really help you with that.  You'll need to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: @servy, sorry for that.. if I was wrong, im simply asking for correct format of schoolYear. im just looking for what would be the best since I'd posted what i have tried.

Comment: spajce, some of the confusion is coming from your repeated request for the *correct format of schoolYear*. This doesn't make sense. Can you rephrase your question, in a way that doesn't use the word "format"? That might help.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta i modified my question..

Comment: @LeeTaylor It's quite interesting... I've seen something very similar a few days ago... Maybe someone stole his password ?

Comment: @LeeTaylor, i didnot notice your comment. if my question is really low quality question, can you post your answer?

Comment: @SoboLAN you're in one of victim of illusion `:D`

Comment: @spajce - Well you've radically changed your question now. In future add all you can when you *first* post your question.

Comment: @LeeTaylor, i understand my question is really not direct to the point because of the __Format__, since my account is _1 year, 2 months old_ im not active user in 7 months `:D`

Comment: @spajce I didn't realise that you had to be a constant user on here to write cogent sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `2013-2014` is a valid format, this might be a function that works:

```
public static bool IsSchoolYearFormat(string format, int minYear, int maxYear)
{
    string[] parts = format.Trim().Split(new[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (parts.Length == 2)
    {
        int fromYear; int toYear;
        if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out fromYear) && int.TryParse(parts[1], out toYear))
        {
            if (fromYear >= minYear && toYear <= maxYear && fromYear + 1 == toYear)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool IsSchoolYearFormat(string toCheck)
{
    string[] arr = toCheck.Trim().Split('-'); //splits the string, eg 2013-2014 goes to 2013 and 2014
    if (arr.Length != 2) //if there is less or more than two school years it is invalid.
    {
        return false;
    }
    int one, two;
    if (!int.TryParse(arr[0], out one))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (!int.TryParse(arr[1], out two))
    {
        return false;
    }
    //if they don't parse then they are invalid.
    return two - 1 == one && two > 1900 && one > 1900; //to please AbZy
    //school year must be in the format yeara-(yeara+1)
}
```

Comment: @Servy Thank you for arguing it for me :) I was busy.

Comment: +1, this answer.. is correct. but seems like mr. @AbZy wants to enter the 1 year `:D`